# Node.js with TypeORM inserts wrong timezones into Azure SQL Database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typeorm, timezone-offset, date-fns

I have a backend written on top of node.js, I'm using [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/) as the ORM and Azure SQL Database to store my data. When I call the ORM's create() and save() functions, I'm passing in the correct date and time as can be seen below. But when I query the inserted data in the server, the timezone has shifted from -03:00 to +00:00. It maybe a normal behavior, since I'm new working with dates though.

This is the code where I call the create() in:

```
class CreateAppointmentsService {
  public async execute({ provider, date }: RequestDTO): Promise<Appointment> {
    const appointmentsRepository = getCustomRepository(AppointmentsRepository);
    const roundDate = startOfHour(date);
    const foundAppointment = await appointmentsRepository.findByDate(roundDate);
    if (foundAppointment) {
      throw Error('This date and time already has a booking.');
    }
    const appointment = appointmentsRepository.create({
      provider,
      date: roundDate,
    });
    await appointmentsRepository.save(appointment);
    return appointment;
  }
}
```

[This is my debug information, showing date and time in expected timezone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWlIL.png)

[This is the data in the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRctg.png) The field type is [datetimeoffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and the server time is set to UTC (+00:00).

Thanks in advance! =)

[EDIT]: Explaining better: the time I posted to the database is rounded to 20:00 -03:00 (America/Sao_Paulo/Brasilia). If you look the column "created_at", the time is updated to UTC, but the column "data" only got the timezone set to +00:00, the time remais 20:00.

Comment: But shouldn't it also update the time too? You see, the time I posted to the database is 20:00 -03:00. If you look the column "created_at", the time is updated to UTC, but the column "data" only got the timezone set to +00:00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem! I forgot to set the "date" column to datetimeoffset in the typeORM model =(.

How it was:

```
  @Column()
  date: Date;
```

Changed to:

```
  @Column('datetimeoffset')
  date: Date;
```

Now it work wonders! The correct timezone is being set alongside the time. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer Dani, feel free to mark this question as answered if your problem is solved. Cheers! 